# jQuery window .scroll dysfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm including the whole code here, it's the bones of a parallax website (all css) with a scrolling menu (jQuery) that displays the current position based on div ID.

The parallax CSS and menu jQuery work perfectly fine when separated, but there's a dysfunction when combined.

I narrowed it down to the window.scroll by logging it in the console and seeing that any time the mouse pointer is hovering over the main content frame (.parallax) while scrolling, nothing is logged. Is there some way to make sure the window's attributes and scroll position are logged regardless of what's in the body section?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('got here');
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log('Log this');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  var debugInput = document.querySelector("input");

  function updateDebugState() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('debug-on', debugInput.checked);
  }
  debugInput.addEventListener("click", updateDebugState);
  updateDebugState();

  var lastId,
    sideMenu = $(".ssb00"),
    menuItems = sideMenu.find("a"),
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) {
        return item;
      }
    });

  menuItems.click(function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top;
    $(window).stop().animate({
      scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 300);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
      if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
        return this;
    });
    cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

    if (lastId !== id) {
      lastId = id;
      menuItems
        .parent().removeClass("active")
        .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("active");
    }
  });

  $(function() {

    var scroll = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
      var moved = $(this).scrollTop();
      var headerSize = 20
      if (moved > headerSize) {
        $('.ssb00').css({
          'opacity': '1',
          'right': '10px'
        })
        $('.ssb01').css({
          'opacity': '0',
        })
      }

      if (moved === 0) {
        $('.ssb00').css({
          'opacity': '0',
          'right': '-40px'
        })
        $('.ssb01').css({
          'opacity': '1',
        })
      }
      if (moved > headerSize) {}
      headerSize = moved;
    });
  });

});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.ssb00 {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#menLogo {
  z-index: 110;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 8px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url(img/Logo-300x244.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.ssb00_inWrap {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50vh - 150px);
}

.m00 {
  height: 33px;
}

.m00 div {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.m01 {
  text-align: left;
  right: 0;
  width: 16px;
}

.m01:before {
  content: '•';
}

.m02 {
  left: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 26px);
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.ssb00_inWrap:hover .m02 {
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ssb00 a {
  color: #fff;
}

.ssb00 a:hover {
  color: #6ccef5;
}

.active .m02 {
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.active a {
  color: #1b75ba;
}

.ssb01 {
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.ssb01 .nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 560px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ssb01 a {
  color: #1b75ba;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

.ssb01 a:hover {
  color: #6ccef5;
}

.ssb01 a:active {
  color: #fff;
}

.ssb01__info {
  position: absolute;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  left: 110px;
  top: 15px;
  color: #666;
  opacity: 1;
}

.trans {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
}

.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__layer--fore {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  z-index: 1;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 4;
}

.parallax__layer--back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  z-index: 3;
}

.parallax__layer--deep {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
  z-index: 2;
}

.debug {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: .5em;
  z-index: 999;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
  color: #fff;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.debug-on .parallax__group {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(800px, 0, -800px) rotateY(30deg);
  transform: translate3d(700px, 0, -800px) rotateY(30deg);
}

.debug-on .parallax__layer {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #000;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.parallax__group {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.parallax {
  font-size: 200%;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#Xabout {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide under groups 1 and 3 */
}

#Xabout .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #6ba1ff;
}

#aboutGal {
  z-index: 5;
  /* slide over group 2 */
}

#aboutGal .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #c4daff;
}

#Xconcept {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide under groups 1 and 3 */
}

#Xconcept .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #7ae570;
}

#conceptGal {
  z-index: 4;
  /* slide over group 2 and 4 */
}

#conceptGal .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #adffa5;
}

#Xbroadcast {
  z-index: 2;
  /* slide under group 3 and 5 */
}

#Xbroadcast .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #f0f760;
}

#broadcastGal {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide over group 4 and 6 */
}

#broadcastGal .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #fcffbc;
}

#Xdigital {
  z-index: 2;
  /* slide under group 5 and 7 */
}

#Xdigital .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #42e2f4;
}

#digitalGal {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide over group 7 */
}

#digitalGal .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #aaf6ff;
}

#Xdesign {
  z-index: 2;
  /* slide under group 5 and 7 */
}

#Xdesign .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #e59172;
}

#designGal {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide over group 7 */
}

#designGal .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #ffe1d6;
}

#Xcontact {
  z-index: 2;
  /* slide under group 5 and 7 */
}

#Xcontact .parallax__layer--back {
  background: rgb(245, 235, 100);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="debug">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Debug</label>
  </div>

  <div id="menLogo"></div>
  <div class="ssb01 trans">
    <div class="ssb01__info">
      <span>bill o'day</span>
      <br />
      <span>creative director | art</span>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#concept">Concept</a>
      <a href="#broadcast">Broadcast</a>
      <a href="#digital">Digital</a>
      <a href="#design">Design</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ssb00 trans">
    <div class="ssb00_inWrap">
      <div class="m00 men-1 active">
        <a href="#about">
          <div class="m01 mm-1"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-1">About</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="m00 men-2 active">
        <a href="#concept">
          <div class="m01 mm-2"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-2">Concept</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="m00 men-3 active">
        <a href="#broadcast">
          <div class="m01 mm-3"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-3">Broadcast</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="m00 men-4 active">
        <a href="#digital">
          <div class="m01 mm-4"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-4">Digital</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="m00 men-5 active">
        <a href="#design">
          <div class="m01 mm-5"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-5">Design</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="m00 men-6 active">
        <a href="#contact">
          <div class="m01 mm-6"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-6">Contact</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="parallax">
    <div id="Xabout" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="about" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">hello</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">ABOUT BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="aboutGal" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">ABOUT GAL</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="Xconcept" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="concept" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">concepts</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Concepts BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="conceptGal" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">CONCEPTS GAL</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="Xbroadcast" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="broadcast" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">broadcast</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">BROADCAST BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="broadcastGal" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">BROADCAST GAL</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="Xdigital" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="digital" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">digital</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">DIGITAL BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="digitalGal" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">DIGITAL GAL</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Xdesign" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="design" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">design</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">DESIGN BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="designGal" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">DESIGN GAL</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Xcontact" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="contact" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">contact</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">CONTACT BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

EDIT:

I've changed my JS .scroll commands to focus on the .parallax div since that's really what should be measured, and it logs just fine now. BUT clicking on the items in the side menu still scrolls to positions as if it has a 30% view of the whole thing.

So I think the issue now is particularly with this line:

```
 offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top;
```

The scrollTop and offsetTop results seem to be off. I'm trying to figure it out but I'm very slow. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to listen to `.parallax` scrolling right?
And you didn't tried this ?

```
$(".parallax").scroll(function() {    // Added, just to console.log the scroll events.
  console.log('Log this Parallax');
});
```

---

In your script, I got rid of the multiple `ready` wrappers.

`$(document).ready(function() {` is the same as `$(function() {`
One is a short hand of the other.
Multiple subsequent wrapper like this are useless... And nested ones too.

---

I also changed this (**And this is what fixes your side menu offset on scroll back up**) :

```
$(".parallax").scroll(function() {        // Changed $(window) to $(".parallax")
  var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();    // Changed $(this) to $(window)
  // ...
```

---

I also fixed the side menu links click handler like this:

```
menuItems.click(function(e) {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");    // changed the coma to a semi-colon.
  var offsetTop = href.offset().top;  // Added var and removed the useless ternary operator:  href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top;
  $(".parallax").stop().animate({     // Changed $(window") to $(".parallax")
    scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

> There is still a small glitch on the appearance of the menus (top and side)...
>   That is because you use `opacity` instead of `display` to control show/hide.
>   That also is the source of the white band at the bottom of the page.
>   
>   I left some work for you ;)

See it on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/owNXMY?editors=1011) and on the below snippet *(but click the "Full page" link)*.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('got here');
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //console.log('Log this');
  });
  $(".parallax").scroll(function() {    // Added, just to console.log the scroll events.
    //console.log('Log this Parallax');
  });
  //});

  //$(document).ready(function() {

  var debugInput = document.querySelector("input");

  function updateDebugState() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('debug-on', debugInput.checked);
  }
  debugInput.addEventListener("click", updateDebugState);
  updateDebugState();

  var lastId,
      sideMenu = $(".ssb00"),
      menuItems = sideMenu.find("a"),
      scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) {
          return item;
        }
      });

  menuItems.click(function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");    // changed the coma to a semi-colon.
    var offsetTop = href.offset().top;  // Added var and removed the useless ternary operator:  href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top;
    $(".parallax").stop().animate({     // Changed $(window") to $(".parallax")
      scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 300);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(".parallax").scroll(function() {        // Changed $(window) to $(".parallax")
    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();    // Changed $(this) to $(window)

    var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
      if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
        return this;
    });
    cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

    if (lastId !== id) {
      lastId = id;
      menuItems
        .parent().removeClass("active")
        .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("active");
    }
  });

  //$(function() {

  var scroll = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var moved = $(this).scrollTop();
    var headerSize = 20
    if (moved > headerSize) {
      $('.ssb00').css({
        'opacity': '1',
        'right': '10px'
      })
      $('.ssb01').css({
        'opacity': '0',
      })
    }

    if (moved === 0) {
      $('.ssb00').css({
        'opacity': '0',
        'right': '-40px'
      })
      $('.ssb01').css({
        'opacity': '1',
      })
    }
    if (moved > headerSize) {}
    headerSize = moved;
  });
  //});

});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.ssb00 {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#menLogo {
  z-index: 110;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 8px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url(img/Logo-300x244.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.ssb00_inWrap {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50vh - 150px);
}

.m00 {
  height: 33px;
}

.m00 div {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.m01 {
  text-align: left;
  right: 0;
  width: 16px;
}

.m01:before {
  content: '•';
}

.m02 {
  left: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 26px);
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.ssb00_inWrap:hover .m02 {
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ssb00 a {
  color: #fff;
}

.ssb00 a:hover {
  color: #6ccef5;
}

.active .m02 {
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.active a {
  color: #1b75ba;
}

.ssb01 {
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.ssb01 .nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 560px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ssb01 a {
  color: #1b75ba;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

.ssb01 a:hover {
  color: #6ccef5;
}

.ssb01 a:active {
  color: #fff;
}

.ssb01__info {
  position: absolute;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  left: 110px;
  top: 15px;
  color: #666;
  opacity: 1;
}

.trans {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
}

.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__layer--fore {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  z-index: 1;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 4;
}

.parallax__layer--back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  z-index: 3;
}

.parallax__layer--deep {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
  z-index: 2;
}

.debug {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: .5em;
  z-index: 999;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
  color: #fff;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.debug-on .parallax__group {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(800px, 0, -800px) rotateY(30deg);
  transform: translate3d(700px, 0, -800px) rotateY(30deg);
}

.debug-on .parallax__layer {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #000;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.parallax__group {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.parallax {
  font-size: 200%;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#Xabout {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide under groups 1 and 3 */
}

#Xabout .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #6ba1ff;
}

#aboutGal {
  z-index: 5;
  /* slide over group 2 */
}

#aboutGal .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #c4daff;
}

#Xconcept {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide under groups 1 and 3 */
}

#Xconcept .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #7ae570;
}

#conceptGal {
  z-index: 4;
  /* slide over group 2 and 4 */
}

#conceptGal .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #adffa5;
}

#Xbroadcast {
  z-index: 2;
  /* slide under group 3 and 5 */
}

#Xbroadcast .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #f0f760;
}

#broadcastGal {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide over group 4 and 6 */
}

#broadcastGal .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #fcffbc;
}

#Xdigital {
  z-index: 2;
  /* slide under group 5 and 7 */
}

#Xdigital .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #42e2f4;
}

#digitalGal {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide over group 7 */
}

#digitalGal .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #aaf6ff;
}

#Xdesign {
  z-index: 2;
  /* slide under group 5 and 7 */
}

#Xdesign .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #e59172;
}

#designGal {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide over group 7 */
}

#designGal .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #ffe1d6;
}

#Xcontact {
  z-index: 2;
  /* slide under group 5 and 7 */
}

#Xcontact .parallax__layer--back {
  background: rgb(245, 235, 100);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="debug">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Debug</label>
  </div>

  <div id="menLogo"></div>
  <div class="ssb01 trans">
    <div class="ssb01__info">
      <span>bill o'day</span>
      <br />
      <span>creative director | art</span>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#concept">Concept</a>
      <a href="#broadcast">Broadcast</a>
      <a href="#digital">Digital</a>
      <a href="#design">Design</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ssb00 trans">
    <div class="ssb00_inWrap">
      <div class="m00 men-1 active">
        <a href="#about">
          <div class="m01 mm-1"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-1">About</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="m00 men-2 active">
        <a href="#concept">
          <div class="m01 mm-2"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-2">Concept</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="m00 men-3 active">
        <a href="#broadcast">
          <div class="m01 mm-3"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-3">Broadcast</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="m00 men-4 active">
        <a href="#digital">
          <div class="m01 mm-4"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-4">Digital</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="m00 men-5 active">
        <a href="#design">
          <div class="m01 mm-5"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-5">Design</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="m00 men-6 active">
        <a href="#contact">
          <div class="m01 mm-6"></div>
          <div class="m02 mm-6">Contact</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="parallax">
    <div id="Xabout" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="about" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">hello</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">ABOUT BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="aboutGal" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">ABOUT GAL</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="Xconcept" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="concept" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">concepts</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Concepts BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="conceptGal" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">CONCEPTS GAL</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="Xbroadcast" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="broadcast" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">broadcast</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">BROADCAST BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="broadcastGal" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">BROADCAST GAL</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="Xdigital" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="digital" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">digital</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">DIGITAL BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="digitalGal" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">DIGITAL GAL</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Xdesign" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="design" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">design</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">DESIGN BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="designGal" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">DESIGN GAL</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Xcontact" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="contact" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">contact</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">CONTACT BG</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I forgot to come back to this because my spaghetti version was working fine, but it'll be good to do it properly with the loops. I actually didn't know that $(function() { was the same as doc.ready, as stupid as that sounds...I wish I'd gone to university for coding instead of literature -_-